# Is this proof of Robert G. Bartle "Introduction to Real Analysis" Chapter 1 #12 correct?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I realize this question has been asked several times but I am not satisfied with the answers.

> **Question 12:**
>   Show that if $f:A\to B$ and $E,F$ are subsets of $A$, then $f(E\cup F)=f(E) \cup f(F)$ and $f(E\cap F)\subseteq f(E) \cap f(F)$

Attempt:

1. Proving $f(E\cup F)=f(E)\cup f(F)$

We know $E,F\subseteq E\cup F$ so $f(E)\cup f(F)\subseteq f(E\cup F)$. How do we show $f(E)\cup f(F) \supseteq f(E\cup F)$ to prove $f(E)\cup f(F)=f(E)\cup f(F)$?

2. Proving $f(E\cap F)\subseteq f(E) \cap f(F)$

We know $E\cap F \subseteq E,F$ so $f(E\cap F)\subseteq f(E)\cap f(F)$. Is this all I need to prove this part?

Edit: If $c\in C$ and $C\subseteq A$ then $c\in A$ so $f(c)\in f(A)$ hence $f(C)\subseteq f(A)$. We apply this to the proofs above replacing $C$ and $A$ with $E,F$, Am I correct?

Comment: You are repeatedly using the fact that $P \subseteq Q \implies f(P) \subseteq f(Q)$. If you haven't proven this statement explicitly in an earlier question, then you should prove it before using it.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If $p\in P$ and $P\subseteq Q$ then $p\in Q$ so $f(p)\in f(Q)$ hence $f(P)\subseteq f(Q)$. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. That's a perfectly good proof of that fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove $f(E\cup F)\subseteq f(E)\cup f(F)$, we can proceed pointwise:

Let $y\in f(E\cup F)$, there is at least one $x\in E\cup F$ such that $y=f(x)$. Since $x\in E\cup F$, we have $x\in E$ or $x\in F$.

If $x\in E$, then $y=f(x)\in f(E)\subseteq f(E)\cup f(F)$.

If $x\in F$, then $y=f(x)\in f(F)\subseteq f(E)\cup f(F)$.

Therefore, independently of where $x$ is, you always get $y\in f(E)\cup f(F)$.

As for the second question: what you've done is enough, so long as you already proved that if $C\subseteq D$, then $f(C)\subseteq f(D)$. Hope this helps!

Comment: If $c\in C$ and $C\subseteq D$ then $c\in C$ so $f(c)\in f(D)$ hence $f(C)\subseteq f(D)$. Am I correct?

Comment: Pretty much. I think the "then $c\in C$" is a typo, and you intended to say "then $c\in D$", right?

Comment: Yes you’re right. Minor mistake.