# Proving $f^{-1}(G\cup H)=f^{-1}(G) \cup f(H)$ and $f^{-1}(G\cap H)= f^{-1}(G) \cap f^{-1}(H)$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

> **"Introduction to Real Analysis" (Robert G. Bartle) Chapter 1, Question 13:**
>   Show that if $f:A\to B$ and $G,H$ are subsets of $B$, then $f^{-1}(G\cup H)=f^{-1}(G) \cup f(H)$ and $f^{-1}(G\cap H)= f^{-1}(G) \cap f^{-1}(H)$

**EDIT: Despite @ArtudoMagdin's comments, I still cannot form a complete, correct solution. I require a full answer. I crossed out the solution verification tag.**

Attempt:

1. Proving $f^{-1}(G\cup H)=f^{-1}(G)\cup f^{-1}(H)$

<s>We know $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f(x)\in G}$ and $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{G\subseteq G\cup H}$ so $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f(x)\in G\cup H}$ meaning $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f^{-1}(G)\subseteq f^{-1}(G\cup H)}$ and $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f(x)\in H}$ and $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{H \subseteq G\cup H}$ so $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f(x)\in G\cup H}$ meaning $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f^{-1}(H)\subseteq f^{-1}(G\cup H)}$. Since $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f(x)}$ is independetly in $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{G}$ or $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{H}$, $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f^{-1}(G)\cup f^{-1}(H) = f^{-1}(G\cup H)}$</s>

<s>**Edit: Here is my new attempt:**</s>

**Second Edit: I made additional changes by the request of @ArturoMagidin**

- 1. If $x\in f^{-1}(G)$  then $f(x) \in G \subseteq G\cup H$, hence $f^{-1}(G)\subseteq f^{-1}(G\cup H)$
- 2. If $x\in f^{-1}(H)$ then $f(x)\in H\subseteq G \cup H$, hence $f^{-1}(H)\subseteq f^{-1}(G\cup H)$
- 3. If $x\in f^{-1}(G)\cup f^{-1}(H)$, it follows 1. and 2. that $f(x)\in G \cup H$ which also means that $x\in f^{-1}(G\cup H)$.
- 4. It follows from 3. that $f^{-1}(G)\cup f^{-1}(H)\subseteq f^{-1}(G\cup H)$
- 5. If $x\in f^{-1}(G\cup H)$ then $f(x)\in G\cup H$, hence $f(x)\in G$ *or* $f(x)\in H$ which means $x\in f^{-1}(G)$ or $x\in f^{-1}(H)$. Hence, $f^{-1}(G\cup H)=f^{-1}(G)\cup f^{-1}(H)$

Is my proof correct, it seems this part is right?

---

2. Proving $f^{-1}(G\cap H)\subseteq f(G) \cap f(H)$

<s>We know $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f(x)\in G}$ and $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{G\supseteq G\cap H}$ so if $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f(x)\in G\cap H}$ meaning $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f^{-1}(G)\supseteq f^{-1}(G\cap H)}$ and $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f(x)\in H}$ and $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{H \supseteq G\cup H}$ so $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f(x)\in G\cup H}$ meaning $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f^{-1}(H)\subseteq f^{-1}(G\cup H)}$. I am not sure how to proceed from here. Is my approach correct? If so, how would this imply that $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f^{-1}(G\cap H)=f^{-1}(G)\cap f^{-1}(H)}$</s>

<s>**Edit: Here is my new attempt for 2.**</s>

<s>**Second Edit: I made additional changes by the request of @ArturoMagidin**</s>

**Third Edit: I shortened my steps per @ArturoMagidin's comments. I figure I could have done the same for the first proof.**

- 1. If $x\in f^{-1}(G)\cap f^{-1}(H)$ then $f(x)\in G$ and $f(x)\in H$ therefore $f(x)\in G\cup H$ so $f^{-1}(G\cap H)\subseteq f^{-1}(G)\cap f^{-1}(H)$
- 2. If $x\in f^{-1}(G\cap H)$ then $f(x)\in G\cap H$, hence $f(x)\in G$ *and* $f(x)\in H$ which means $x\in f^{-1}(G)$ and $x\in f^{-1}(H)$. Hence, $f^{-1}(G\cap H) \supseteq f^{-1}(G)\cap f^{-1}(H)$
- 3. From 1. and 2. we state that $f^{-1}(G\cap H)\subseteq f^{-1}(G)\cap f^{-1}(H)$

<s>I am not satisfied with step 5.? How do we show $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f^{-1}(G\cap H)\supseteq f^{-1}(G)\cap f^{-1}(H)}$?</s>

Is this correct? **EDIT: According to @ArtudoMagdin, it is still wrong. What is the full solution for this proof?**

Comment: First proof: I would separate the final part of step 3 into a new “step”. That is a conclusion, whereas all previous parts were conditionals/implications.  Step 4 is not correctly predicated. Steps 1 and 2 give implications *the wrong way for your purpose*. Step 1, for example, says that **if** $x\in f^{-1}(G)$, **then** $f(x)\in G$. But in step 4 you need that **if** $f(x)\in G$, **then** $x\in f^{-1}(G)$. That is not what step 1 says. For the same reason, the invocation of step 2 is also improper.

Comment: Second proof: First step is wrong. Having an element in a larger set does not tell you, in any way, shape, or form, that another set is contained in the larger one. For the same reason, step 2 is also incorrect. Step 3 invokes steps that do not prove what you want, even if they were correct.  Step 4 has the same error as step 4 of the first proof.

Comment: In summary: the first argument is almost right; the second argument is completely wrong.

Comment: (Also, the point of step 1 in the first proof is to show that $f^{-1}(G)\subseteq f^{-1}(G\cup H)$, so it is not proper to invoke the step as a whole to prove that $f(x)\in G$ implies $x\in f^{-1}(G)$.)

Comment: Please make your titles descriptive. Telling me where you got this problem *from* is irrelevant for the actual problem.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin How is my proof now? Is it better? Does it need more work?

Comment: @AsafKaragila How is my proof? Does it need more work?

Comment: Proof 1 is correct, thought I would say you are missing a step in the last bit, going from “$f(x)\in G$ or $f(x)\in H$” to $f(x)\in G\cup H$, and *then* to $x\in f^{-1}(G\cup H)$, and **then** reach your conclusion.

Comment: Second proof is still a mess. Your claim in step 2 that step 1 implies something about the direct image is incorrect. Step 1 is about inverse images, it cannot imply something about direct images. Step 3 is likewise incorrect. Steps 2, 3, and 4 are about direct images, **which is immaterial for what you are trying to prove.** You are trying to prove something about inverse images; why are you spending so much time proving things about direct images instead? Interestingly step 5 is*great*, yet it is the one you say you are not satisfied with. That suggests a lot of confusion on your part.

Comment: And indeed, you have **not proven** that $f^{-1}(G)\cap f^{-1}(H)\subseteq f^{-1}(G\cap H)$. Take $x\in f^{-1}(G)\cap f^{-1}(H)$. Then $f(x)\in G$ and $f(x)\in H$, so $f(x)\in G\cap H$. Therefore .....

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think my proof is correct now. Also in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3671461/is-this-proof-of-robert-g-bartle-introduction-to-real-analysis-chapter-1-12?rq=1) how do we show that $f(E \cap F)\not\supseteq f(E)\cap f(F)$?

Comment: Your first step has what I think is a typo, with $G\cup H$ where you mean $G\cap H$. And your stated conclusion in Step 1 is **the exact opposite** of what you actually argued. Your step 2 is missing steps, yet again. You need to go from $f(x)\in G$ and $f(x)\in H$ to $f(x)\in G\cap H$, to $x\in f^{-1}(G\cap H)$.  Why do you insist on skipping these steps, even after I point them out multiple times, is beyond me. Also, the conclusion you write in step 2 is **the exact opposite** of what you’ve actually proven (your inclusion sign is the wrong one). Still something of a mess.

Comment: And please don’t use one question to ask people to look at unrelated questions. That’s not what the comments are for.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin How about you stop calling my proofs a "mess", highlighting in **bold** and stating I am "beyond you"

Comment: Bold for emphasis; it’s still “a bit of a mess” because your conclusions are the opposite of what you did before; and it is not you who are beyond me, but the insistence on committing the same error over and over even after it has been pointed out. You have requested my criticisms three times now, and even tried to get me to comment on a separate post. Are you now complaining about that criticism because you are frustrated?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You know what. I am poor at this problem. I still do not fully understand your criticisms and I know you will not show the complete answer. I remember one time (with my physics labs) a graduate teaching assistant gave up guiding me, giving the answer and muttering a swear word. I am tired of being insulted.....yes I am fustrated

Comment: I have not insulted you; if you perceived a personal insult when I am criticising your work, be aware that no such insult was intended. Your first proof is essentially done; the second proof should be quite similar. If you want a full solution, you may ask for one, but you tagged this post “solution-verification”. This is meant to be an indication that you do not want a solution worked out for you, but want people to review your solution and point out errors, and guide (but not fully provide) an answer as needed.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Apologies, can I have the full answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your proof is not complete, and it is also rather confusing. You are trying to prove $f^{-1}(G\cup H)=f^{-1}(G)\cup f^{-1}(H)$, and you start by saying “We know that $f(x)\in G$.”

Wait a second! What is $x$? Where did it come from? What are you trying to prove here? I don’t know who $x$ is, so I certainly do not know what happens to $x$ under $f$.

Same thing with the second proof.

You really need to be more intentional. It appears you are trying to prove the equality by double inclusion. Fine. So then start with an element of one side. So, “We want to show that $f^{-1}(G)\cup f^{-1}(H)\subseteq f^{-1}(G\cup H)$ first. To that end, let $x\in f^{-1}(G)$. Then $f(x)\in G\subseteq G\cup H$, so $x\in f^{-1}(G\cup H)$. Therefore, we have $f^{-1}(G)\subseteq f^{-1}(G\cup H)$.” Then you do the same thing with $x\in f^{-1}(H)$. Then you want to argue this shows $f^{-1}(G)\cup f^{-1}(H)\subseteq f^{-1}(G\cup H)$.

But at this point you have not proven equality. You have only proven one inclusion. So you are not done. Now you must show that if $x\in f^{-1}(G\cup H)$, then it must be the case that $x\in f^{-1}(G)\cup f^{-1}(H)$. And you have not done so.

Similar problems occur with your argument so far for the second part. Not only do you apparently start in the middle of the argument, you are comparing the wrong things.

For the second part, let us first show that $f^{-1}(G\cap H)\subseteq f^{-1}(G)\cap f^{-1}(H)$. Let $x\in f^{-1}(G\cap H)$. Then $f(x)\in G\cap H\subseteq G$, so $x\in f^{-1}(G)$.

Now you should be able to show that we also have $x\in f^{-1}(H)$. Then you want to argue this shows $x\in f^{-1}(G)\cap f^{-1}(H)$. This will show *one inclusion*. Not equality (yet).

So then you want to take $x\in f^{-1}(G)\cap f^{-1}(H)$, and show it lies in $f^{-1}(G\cap H)$. Well, $f(x)\in G$ because $x\in f^{-1}(G)$; and $f(x)\in H$ because....

... and finish it off.

---

**Added** (May 13, 15:35 CDT)

A proof of the second part proceeds along the same lines.

To prove that $f^{-1}(G\cap H)\subseteq f^{-1}(G)\cap f^{-1}(H)$, let $x\in f^{-1}(G\cap H)$. Then $f(x)\in G\cap H$, hence $f(x)\in G$ and $f(x)\in H$. This means that $x\in f^{-1}(G)$, and $x\in f^{-1}(H)$, and therefore that $x\in f^{-1}(G)\cap f^{-1}(H)$, proving the inclusion.

To prove that $f^{-1}(G)\cap f^{-1}(H)\subseteq f^{-1}(G\cap H)$, let $x\in f^{-1}(G)\cap f^{-1}(H)$. Then $x\in f^{-1}(G)$, so $f(x)\in G$; and $x\in f^{-1}(H)$, so $f(x)\in H$. Therefore, $f(x)\in G\cap H$, and thus by definition we have $x\in f^{-1}(G\cap H)$.  This proves the second inclusion, and hence the equality.

Comment: Arturo, congratulations, very good answer

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Check my new attempt. I am not completely done yet. I require additional information.

Comment: @Arbuja: Are you asking me, or ordering me?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am kindly asking you.

Comment: @Angelo Is it possible to check my new attempt.

Comment: @Arbuja: Well, “is it possible to check?” is certainly better than “Check my attempt”...